# How to install a junction box for a wire splice

Tags: electrical, wiring

My unit is getting ready to sell and the home inspector said I need to install a junction box ... I don't know what to do. Is this something my association management should take care of? How can I put a junction box on this? This is where it is in my kitchen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get us a shot of where the wires enter the light fixture?

Comment: Hard to see what's going on in that small fuzzy photo. Can you improve it or revise to describe what we're seeing a bit better?

Comment: To clarify, is the 2nd image with the text taken from the inspector's write up, and the first image of the kitchen shows a broad view of the light in the 2nd image? It's entirely possible that the light fixture itself has an accommodation for the wiring built right into it, but we'll need good, sharp close ups to know for sure. You may also want to pop the translucent plastic piece off the light an get a pic of inside. [Edit] you post to include the pics, just like you did with the originals.

Comment: Also, nice job for your first post! Many people don't bother with _any_ pics, so you're miles ahead! After you've added the pics, take the [tour] so you can learn how to make the most of the site.

Comment: You may be able to move the light fixture back and have the wire go directly into the fixture , the junction could be made inside the light fixture and be legal but the Romex can not be exposed the inspector is correct.

Comment: Just hire somebody, this kind of situation is not a good fit for DIY work, a newbie stumbling through electrical work with no motive except to clear an inspection report to get to close.  There is nil incentive for you to do all the skilling-up required to do the job properly, so it's liable to turn into a warranty claim that comes back on you, or worse, a fire.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the root problem is that the under-cabinet light was not installed flush to the back of the cabinet-wall corner.  The casing of the light itself is typically meant to be used as a junction box, and it should have enclosed the wires from the light, from the wall, the wire nuts, etc.

You should remove the light, feed the cable from the wall through the existing hole in the light fixture, reinstall the fixture absolutely flush the with cabinet bottom and wall, and then re-attach the wires inside the fixture. You may need to trim the wires a bit, or maybe you can just gently push the extra inches back into the wall (probably better).

If the hole in the fixture doesn't already have a clamp or you will need to add one (secures the cable & protects it from metal edges). Personally I like the the plastic snap-in type ([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KKU22Q)) since they're easy and fairly flush. But there are others; your local store can advise you what they have.

The reason for insisting on there being no gaps is so that the wall cable is not exposed even a little; I believe if its done that way it will satisfy electrical code. References: just what I recall reading when I was installing similar lights myself.

Comment: They'll also need a NM connector on the hole in the junction box

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel good point, thanks I've added that